# How do I remove bookmarks from Terminal window?

Tags: terminal, macos, bookmarks

With El Capitan, the Terminal app can automatically create marks, and bookmarks. However, there seems no obvious way to *delete* a bookmark that one's created (by accident). How can one *delete* a Terminal window bookmark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the line in the terminal with the bookmark, and select "Unmark"

Comment: Nice succinct answer. +1  A screen capture with the context menu shown would add lots  of value to the answer.  Oh...and welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Based on the online help (ie Help menu) it seems like it's _supposed_ to work, yet it doesn't…

Answer (score 4):

I double this is an issue still, however, I thought I would answer it for anyone else who comes across this minor problem.

In El Capitan, Bookmarks are not saved across different Terminal sessions. Therefore, after exiting/re-opening Terminal, your bookmarks are cleared. If you want to have the same effect as this, you may use CMD+K.

Comment: Be advised, CMD+K is `Clear to start`, aka clear the terminal screen.

Comment: It's still a problem on Mojave, three full versions and years later. You can actually "Unmark" (from the Mark submenu) a bookmark (in Mojave, at least), but it will still display in the Terminal. It only changes the behavior, which seems worse. After unmarking the bookmark, Clear to Last Bookmark will ignore that bookmark, and either go to the previous one, or if there are none, the start. Valid bookmarks are only accurately tracked in Edit->Bookmarks.